# How to Using Powerbuilder in Mdb

Tags: ms-access, powerbuilder

Windows os : WIndows XP

Pb ver : 6.5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyjnw.jpg)

DataWindow

SQLSTATE = S1003

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The program type out of range.

The error is as follows When the output.

1. DataWindow Profiles

   > ODBC > Config ODBC > Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb) > Create
   >
   > original Data Name : mdb
   >
   > Select DataBase : C:\Program Files\test\test.mdb
   >
   > Create
   >
   > Connect is ok
2. DataWindow

   > DataWindow painter > New(Create New DataWindow)
   >
   > DataSource : SQL Select
   >
   > Presentation style : All Style : SQLSTATE = S1003

---

> DataWindow painter > New(Create New DataWindow)
>
> DataSource : With the exception of the 'SQL Select'
>
> Presentation style : All Style : Not Print SQLSTATE = S1003
>
> But The contents of this mdb does not come out anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/014vz.jpg)

How to Using PowerBuilder in Mdb File?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is that the version of PowerBuilder you are using is 18 years old. The PB ODBC interface in that version may not be compatible with the version of Access you have.

Answer (score 0):

With version 6 can connect seamlessly with Access, you can search for videos on YouTube where they can help.

Opens google and search for "Powerbuilder 6.5 access" and go to paragraph videos.